# Figures in llncs class

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like to display the figure in my LaTeX file. I use the class

```
\documentclass{llncs}
```

and downloaded `psfig.sty` and add to `/miktex 2.9/tex/latex/base` and then from Setting -> Refresh FNDB. I also include this part of code

```
\input{psfig.sty}
```

then I used this code to insert the image

```
\begin{figure}
\psfig{figure=File.eps}
\caption{my figure label}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}
```

and no image is shown.

I have tried to include this as well `\usepackage{graphicx}` but nothing happens
in fact, I have download the template and recompiled it but no images also appear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

`psfig` is an ancient package which was mainly used in LaTeX 2.09 (ie prior to 1993) when LaTeX did not have a standard graphic inclusion mechanism. Are you *sure* you need to use it now. The `graphics` and `graphicx` packages are a required part of every latex distribution so you should not have to download anything, just add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in your preamble, and

```
 \includegraphics{File}
```

where you want the image to appear.